# PHP - adding an object with its properties to array

Tags: php, arrays, function, object, properties

I have a problem with modifying an array.

```
foreach ($page->getResults() as $lineItem) {
  print_r($lineItem->getTargeting()->getGeoTargeting()->getExcludedLocations());
}
```

This code gives a result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Google\AdsApi\Dfp\v201611\Location Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 2250
            [type:protected] => COUNTRY
            [canonicalParentId:protected] =>
            [displayName:protected] => France
        )
)
```

I'm trying to add another, [1] , same type of object to this array.

I made a class to create and add an object:

```
class Location{
    public function createProperty($propertyName, $propertyValue){
        $this->{$propertyName} = $propertyValue;
    }
}

$location = new Location();
$location->createProperty('id', '2792');
$location->createProperty('type', 'COUNTRY');
$location->createProperty('canonicalParentId', '');
$location->createProperty('displayName', 'Turkey');    

array_push($lineItem->getTargeting()->getGeoTargeting()->getExcludedLocations(), $location);
```

Then, if I pass this into print_r() function

```
print_r($lineItem->getTargeting()->getGeoTargeting()->getExcludedLocations());
```

It shows the same result.

In the end, I need to send this updated whole $lineItem to this function

```
$lineItems = $lineItemService->updateLineItems(array($lineItem));
```

But seems like before sending I can't properly add an object to the array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Arrays in PHP can have elements of different types. Your code should work even if the objects in the array are different. Look for other problems in your code

Comment: The line you're using to both `array_push` and `print_r` is a method that is read only and used to `get` the excluded locations from your object. It would suggest to me that your issue is you're reading from the object, and not saving anything to the object. Try assigning the `...getExcludedLocations()` result to a variable, like `$excludedLocations`. Then `array_push` to that variable to update it. Then commit that variable back to `...setExcludedLocations()` (used to set the locations on the object) to update the object. then you can commit the object back.

Comment: Hi Luke, Thnanks for your reply. I updated as you said $excludedLocations =   $lineItem->getTargeting()->getGeoTargeting()->getExcludedLocations();
array_push($excludedLocations, $location);  if I print this variable it shows two elements. Could you tell me, how do I need to set it to object to save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP returns arrays as a value instead of as a reference. This means you must set the modified value back somehow.

Looking at the [library](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/) apparently in question, there seems to be [`setExcludedLocations`](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/25.2.0/src/Google/AdsApi/Dfp/v201611/GeoTargeting.php#L62) method for that purpose.

So your code should be something like:

```
$geo_targeting = $lineItem->getTargeting()->getGeoTargeting();
$excluded_locations = $geo_targeting->getExcludedLocations();
array_push($excluded_locations, $location);
$geo_targeting->setExcludedLocations($excluded_locations);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is was a solution to the problem.